# How can I speed up this Quartz 2D draw loop that does many ellipse fills?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, swift, quartz-2d

I have an application that does thousands of circular fills that can vary independently in each frame.  Quartz is pretty fast at this and I can get about 30fps on an iPhone 6 with the example below with -Ofast, -Ounchecked.  However I’d like to optimize this as much as possible.

Things I’ve tried or considered:

1) Drawing a cached image instead of filling the ellipse: The code that I tried for this technique is commented out in the example since I am hoping it can be made faster.  What I’ve found is that for the fill sizes in the example it’s about the same but as the fills get larger it’s much slower than simply drawing.  (This contradicts what I found in Java when I tried this.)

2) Filling rectangles behind an image Mask:  Filling rectangles is much faster than filling ellipses, however when I add clipping to a mask it’s way slower.  I have some code for this if anyone wants me to post it (trying to keep this short).

3) The Metal API:  From what I’ve read I could use a geometry shader to render scale appropriate circle geometry right on the GPU.  My fear is that this is a worst case scenario for the GPU since all of the vertex data can change independently on every frame.  I don’t have any intuition about how fast this would be and it’s a lot to learn unless I’m sure it would be a huge improvement.

Here is a test UIView that is representative of the problem (I've left out color to make the image bit simpler for the example).  It's written in Swift but I'm happy to move parts to objc if it helps (I don't think Swift is the issue here).  Note that the relative performance of techniques varies a lot with the maxPartSize.  I'm looking for any way that can speed this up.  Thanks.

```
class TestView: UIView
{
    var parts: [Part]!
    var start:NSDate!
    var drawCount = 0 // for fps counter
    var image: UIImage! // for the image approach
    let maxPartSize: CGFloat = 10.0

    override func drawRect(screenRect: CGRect)
    {
        if ( self.start == nil) { self.start = NSDate() }
        if ( self.parts == nil ) { setupParts(screenRect) }

        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        for (var i=0; i<parts.count; i++) {
            let part = parts[i]
            var drawRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(part.x), CGFloat(part.y), CGFloat(part.size), CGFloat(part.size))

            // Draw 2D
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
            CGContextSetAlpha(context, CGFloat(part.trans))
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, drawRect)

            // Draw with image. (This is faster for small values of maxPartSize, much slower otherwise)
            // CGContextSetAlpha(context, CGFloat(part.trans))
            // CGContextDrawImage(context, drawRect, getImage().CGImage)
       }

        drawCount++
        if ( drawCount%100 == 0 ) {
            let fps: Double = Double(drawCount) / NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
            println("\(fps) fps")
        }
    }

    func setupParts( rect: CGRect ) {
        self.parts = []
        let numParts = 2000
        for(var i=0; i<numParts; i++ ) {
            let x=randomFloat()*Float(rect.width)
            let y=randomFloat()*Float(rect.height)
            let size = randomFloat() * Float(maxPartSize)
            let trans=randomFloat()
            parts.append( Part( x:x, y:y, size:size, trans:trans) )
        }
    }

    func getImage() -> UIImage
    {
        if ( self.image != nil ) { return self.image }
        var size = CGSizeMake(maxPartSize, maxPartSize)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, maxPartSize, maxPartSize) )
        var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.image = image;
        return image
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        startAnimating()
    }

    func refreshView() { self.setNeedsDisplay(); }

    func startAnimating() {
        var updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: Selector("refreshView"))
        updater.frameInterval = 1
        updater.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes )
    }

}

final class Part {
    var x:Float, y:Float, size: Float, trans: Float 
    init( x:Float, y:Float, size:Float, trans:Float ) {
        self.x = x; self.y = y; self.size = size; self.trans = trans
    }
}

func randomFloat() -> Float {  return Float( arc4random() ) /  Float(UInt32.max) }
```

Comment: The only other thing I can think of (that would be more performant) would be to create `CGMutablePathRef` and add ellipses to it. Then at the end, do one fill. This is less flexible since you wont be able to specify the the alpha and color of each component. Apart from that, I would probably resort to using instanced rendering in OpenGLES 3.0 (via `glDrawElementsInstanced`)

Comment: Have you looked into using `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: Instanced drawing with OpenGL or Metal sounds good.  If anyone knows of a good example that might help me get started with something like the above please let me know.  Thanks.